# WebView doesnt display tweet properly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to know what im doing wrong?

the code im inserting is this, given by twitter:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p>Gracias <a href="https://twitter.com/FelipaoCaicedo">@FelipaoCaicedo</a> por ser parte de nuestro proyecto y así ayudar alimentar el sueño de nuestros niños. <a href="http://t.co/e2q21Gai3f">pic.twitter.com/e2q21Gai3f</a></p>— Fundación EL NINE (@FundacionELNINE) <a href="https://twitter.com/FundacionELNINE/statuses/387664123439628288">October 8, 2013</a></blockquote>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Thats the code that twitter gives me but still it shows me this

[image]

I want to get some thing like this

[image]

Comment: Since `WKWebView` you should implement both delegates (`WKNavigationDelegate` and `WKUIDelegate`) of webView if want to open twitter page on tap.

Answer (score 5):

Two options:

First option is to pass the twitter API URL as the baseURL when calling loadHTMLString on your UIWebView:

```
NSString *tweet = @"<blockquote class=\"twitter-tweet\"><p>Gracias <a href=\"https://twitter.com/FelipaoCaicedo\">@FelipaoCaicedo</a> por ser"
"parte de nuestro proyecto y así ayudar alimentar el sueño de nuestros niños. <a href=\"http://t.co/e2q21Gai3f\">pic.twitter.com/e2q21Gai3f</a></p>"
"— Fundación EL NINE (@FundacionELNINE) <a href=\"https://twitter.com/FundacionELNINE/statuses/387664123439628288\">October 8, 2013</a></blockquote>"
"<script async src=\"//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js\" charset=\"utf-8\"></script>";

[_webView loadHTMLString:tweet baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://platform.twitter.com"]];
```

Second option is to explicitly include `http:` in the src property of the Twitter script:

```
NSString *tweet = @"<blockquote class=\"twitter-tweet\"><p>Gracias <a href=\"https://twitter.com/FelipaoCaicedo\">@FelipaoCaicedo</a> por ser"
"parte de nuestro proyecto y así ayudar alimentar el sueño de nuestros niños. <a href=\"http://t.co/e2q21Gai3f\">pic.twitter.com/e2q21Gai3f</a></p>"
"— Fundación EL NINE (@FundacionELNINE) <a href=\"https://twitter.com/FundacionELNINE/statuses/387664123439628288\">October 8, 2013</a></blockquote>"
"<script async src=\"http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js\" charset=\"utf-8\"></script>";

[_webView loadHTMLString:tweet baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: you save my day boss !!